# How to upload sql database using FileZilla

Tags: database, wordpress, upload

Where to upload database using filezilla but i dont have phpmyadmin and cpanel.i uploaded files into www folder but when i go to website it says that database is not connected but i dont know where to upload it

Comment: You cannot upload a database via FTP, have you got that website working with a newly set up database?

Comment: My website is not working because databse is not connected, but when i bought hosting i didnt got cpanel, and now i dont know how to upload database.

Comment: Can you SSH to your server? If you can't, i don't think if there is a way to do it, unless you contact the hosting company for the information you need.

Comment: I am really sorry but i dont know what means ssh

Comment: Looks like it's gonna be difficult for you to get it working, contact them.

Comment: Ok, but can i install phpmyadmin using filezilla?